# How to store data from filedialog.askopenfilename?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, tk-toolkit, filedialog

I cant figure out how to store value from filedialog.askopenfilename. Now i saved the value to local variable but i want to work with this value later in other functions. I cant return the this value because i call function when i am creating the button. However i want to avoid using global variable. How can i do this? Is there some other way?
Here is code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
def browse_files():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.txt*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
    print(filename)
root = Tk()
button1 = ttk.Button(root,text='Browse', command=browse_files)
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Comment: Add `global filename` at the beginning of `browse_files()` to make `filename` a global variable.  Note that `filename` does not exist until `browse_files()` is executed.

Comment: @acw1668 I know that but i want to avoid using global variable.

Comment: Use class then.

Comment: @acw1668 how can i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using class and instance variable:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = None

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Browse', command=self.browse_files)
        button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text='Show', command=self.show)
        button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def browse_files(self):
        # use instance variable self.filename
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                                   title="Select a File",
                                                   filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt*"),
                                                              ("all files", "*.*")))

    def show(self):
        print(self.filename)

root = App()
root.mainloop()
```